# Mozilla Firefox Graphic Rendering is Glitchy (Ubuntu 14)

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I am using Firefox 31 & it does not render smoothly AT ALL. Almost every time I switch pages or the DOM re-flows, it will jump between the last image and the new image.

If I watch the browser through an application like Google Hangouts or Skype, you do not see the glitches. For this reason I am led to believe that it isn't my Ubuntu causing the issue, but Firefox itself.

I have thought that it could be a graphic's card driver issue, or an issue with my Firefox installation. I have reinstalled Firefox once and the issue persists. I have switched my graphic's card driver from NVIDIA Proprietary to NVIDA (nvidia-343) open source driver and, still, the issue persists.

Any thoughts, comments, or solutions would be very welcome. This becomes EXTREMELY annoying since I do front-end development & use Firefox's dev tools. Please, let me know if you need more information and I will get it to you as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue few months ago, i managed to solve that problem by uninstalling the (lastest) nvidia drivers and installing an old version, which solves the problem at the end. Seems like problem caused by a bug on the lastest nvidia drivers, which can be avoided by a downgrade. The buggy nvidia driver was 340.65 in my case.